# Displaying an empty UITableView row by using an empty 2D string array in swift 4

Tags: uitableview, uikit, swift4

I am trying to display an empty row in the UITableView by using an empty 2D string array but keep on getting the “Index out of range” error on the "cell.textLabel?.text" line. Can someone please help me? Thank you.

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var titleDiplay = [[String]()]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(titleDiplay)

    }

    // MARK: Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return titleDiplay.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = titleDiplay[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Pass titleDisplay.count to number of section and pass titleDisplay[section].count in number of rows in section

Comment: @NisargShah   It worked! Thank you so much.